# Fifth field of crontab

Tags: cron

I am new to LINUX. I have a clear idea on how cron works, but suddenly a small doubt struck at my mind. Suppose if I want to execute `ls` command on 5th march 5.30AM, then my `cron` command will be `30 05 05 03 ??` ls.

My simple question is that what entry will come on `??` place. And suppose if I enter `01` in that position instead of `??` , what will happen. Please excuse me if this is a simple question and please help me solve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case

```
30    05    05  03   *        command to be executed
-     -     -   -    -
|     |     |   |    |
|     |     |   |    +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
|     |     |   +------- month (1 - 12)
|     |     +--------- day of        month (1 - 31)
|     +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

`??` says that you don't mind the day of the week because you are already stating the exact date. If you place the `01` it would still run but its redundant.

Comment: The marker you're looking for is `*` rather than `??`. Unless you have a version of `cron` that differs from most others :-)

Comment: so suppose if I use 01 at that place instead of ??, then this job executes on 05th march 5.30AM only if its a monday. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. That means that if the next 5-march @ 5:30AM is not a monday, it won't run.

Answer (score 1):

The character `*` means "any value" in the crontab file so that's what you'd use.

If you used `1`, your job would only execute on the conditions you'd already specified *AND* it was a Monday.

Answer (score 1):

That entry is for the day of the week you want it to run on. If you put `01` there then it will only run at 5:30 on March 5ths that happen to be a Monday. If you want to specify "any day of the week" then use `*`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd enter `*` which means "Anything is OK here."  That field is the day-of-week, and you don't care if it's a Monday or Tuesday etc.  If you enter `01` you will get it to run only in years when that date is a Monday.